# Where can I find the planned and flown paths for certain flight routes?

Tags: datasets, flight-path

Are there official definitions of air traffic corridor pathing? Specifically European & Mediterranean routes.

I'm working on an application that needs this input data to perform an analysis. I and others in my company have been unable to find anything, and I really don't want to have to derive something approximating it myself if I don't have to.

Edit: Since what I'm asking for doesn't seem to be very clear I'll try a different way.

When an commercial jet starts a flight from one airport to another. I assume it had a generally predetermined path (or options of paths). These are not straight shortest path between two points on an ellipsoid so the data at [OpenFlights.org](http://openflights.org/data.html) isn't helpful, as it is not accurate enough. Obviously though no one can fully predict exactly where an aircraft will be in the future because that changes in respect to many different unknown variables, but I need something more like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m_RLYwqklWhjR5QdeLrqyjRRmgQ&usp=sharing), which was done tracking one commercial jet from one airport to another which includes no amount of variation, and it takes a long time to do this live.

Ideally I could get the general routes that these individual flights tend to follow, but to get an approximation of the actual routes between airports would be a whole lot better than I am know.

In a perfect world there would be lat/lon/alt/ pairings of the paths with some sort of standard deviation on those points. I doubt that exists but anything that could get me closer to that would be excellent.

Paying for something is not necessarily a problem, as long as I can prove it to my boss that it is what we need.

Comment: `Are there official definitions of air traffic corridor pathing` please try to rephrase this.  Are you asking if there are defined paths (routes)?

Comment: What do you need it for? Perhaps if you explained, it would shed some light on what you actually need.

Comment: There are airways (that is the term you should probably be searching for) defined, but they are not always used.

Comment: [Here](http://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/eurocontrol-regional-charts-erc) are charts of airways for Eurocontrol. With the availability of GPS navigation aircraft can now fly more direct routes so fewer aircraft are using airways for navigation.

Comment: @ simon. I may not be using the best terms. I'm asking, "What are the defined routes?" and/or "Where can I find them?".

Comment: @Jan Hudec. I can't share what exactly I need them for, but I need to be able to perform analysis on an estimation of where aircraft should be traveling at an undetermined future time if that helps any.

Comment: @ TomMcW. I think that might be in the right direction, but without actual lat/lon definitions, I'm not sure it would be any less trouble than me making my own interpolations from live flight data.

Comment: You might try [Navigraph](https://www.navigraph.com/fmsdata.aspx) as a start.  There are a course other providers but this is one I know.  It contains every airway in the world. [Here's an example for an airway called B330](http://olravet.fr/AideArinc/MTCA2.jpg) to see wha AIRAC data looks like. The difficult part is to associate flights with airways, especially as the same aircaft, operated by the same airline, can use different airways from day to day and generally, not predictable in advance.

Comment: Related question? [Does official source of data about air routes exists?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/15519)

Comment: @fooot yes that is a related question, but it doesn't have an answer.

Comment: @simon. Thank you. I'll look into that more, it looks promising. My company's web filter won't let me go to the second link due to "adult content"... And that is why I'm trying to find all the possible routes, so that the information can be preprocessed and a lookup done when the important time comes.

Comment: I've just realised the image misses something.  The AIRAC data contains the lat long of every waypoint along the route.

Comment: Here's an extract from an actual AIRAC data file. I've separated with pipes. Each group is airway, waypoint index, waypoint id, lat, long.  N163 001 MTG 43.386306 5.086833 |
N163 002 JULEE 43.012778 5.633333 |
N163 003 EPOLO 42.882778 6.534722 |
N163 004 OMARD 43.104722 7.591111

Comment: That looks like what I need. I will look into it more in depth and get back. Early next week hopefully (unless work pulls me onto something else...). thank you very much. This has probably been the best lead I've gotten since starting to look a few weeks ago.

Comment: A good starting point would be the Wikipedia article on [flight planning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_planning). You may also look at sites that propose to share known routes between airports, like [Flight Plan Database](https://flightplandatabase.com/).

Comment: @mins Thank you. I'll look into that as well.

Comment: @Simon Still waiting to hear back from Navigraph...

Comment: Just an update: Navigraph told me their data is only for non-professional fligh simulation use and directed me to their supplier Jeppesen, Inc. They also noted a site called skyvector.com which definitely has the data, but I haven't had time to see if I could extract it from there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, depending..... 
On FlightAware.com you can see the routing of a flight after it's flown, and the same flight the next day will probably file for the same route.

On FltPlan.com you can find typical routes that a plane is likely to be cleared on and have actually been cleared on over time. Pretty accurate, but you probably need flying skills to interpret it, or get training on understanding routing, airport ICAO codes, nav fixes, departures arrival and enroute routing.

Comment: If my memory serves flightaware has an api.  You might be able to get the flights paths from it.